# Vuforia + ArCore Camera is blur

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have exported a vuforia application to android Java project, I added an AR meta tag since it's needed on Google play store.
Below it is :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="optional" />
```

plus the dependency :

```
implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.18.0'
```

But when I remove the meta-tag for AR, the camera becomes clear without being blur.

Anyone with any idea  ?

**EDIT:**

I had exported a vuforia project to Android java, then I made a library out of the exported project with an AAR format e.g `filename.aar`.

After that, I imported the library/aar file into the android java project, and I added the dependency above plus the ARCore metadata, and the issue resulted.

Am wondering why the issue is making my camera blur.

Answer (score 0):

Want I did was to comment out this :

```
implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.18.0'
```

And it worked like charm